# Extract all .gz file in folder using VBA Shell command

Tags: shell, vba, excel, extract

I have the following VBA code to extract all the files within a given directory.

```
Sub extractAllFiles()

    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
    Dim shellStr As String

    file = Dir("C:\Downloads\")
    While (file <> "")
        If InStr(file, ".gz") > 0 Then
            shellStr = "winzip32 -e C:\Downloads\" & file & " C:\Downloads\"
            Call Shell(shellStr, vbHide)
        End If
        file = Dir
    Wend

End Sub
```

When I execute this sub routine I get a Run-Time error 53, "File Not Found" error. When I copy the shellStr... Example: `winzip32 -e C:\Downloads\file1.gz C:\Downloads\` and execute it from command prompt, it works perfectly! I get the text file within file1.gz extracted to the downloads directory. However running it from VBA doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try with the full path of the shell command, like this, that worked for me:

```
Sub extractAllFiles()

  Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
  Dim shellStr As String

  file = Dir("C:\Downloads\")
  While (file <> "")
    If InStr(1, file, ".gz") > 0 Then
      shellStr = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\winzip32 -e C:\Downloads\" & file & " C:\Downloads\"
      Call Shell(shellStr, vbHide)
    End If
    file = Dir
  Wend

End Sub
```

My winzip is installed as C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\winzip32. You should use yours.
Your install path may be:

```
C:\Program Files\WinZip\winzip32
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe it. I was missing the path to winzip. Just tried it and worked like a charm. One question though, how do I prevent the windows explorer from popping up to show the contents of the directory after it has been extracted?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. It was a setting in WinZip under decompress options.

Comment: This is rather a Winzip behavior. It's useful when I launched winzip from Access VBA, to see the directory. I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

WinZip path needs to be absolute path:

C:\Program Files\WinZip\winzip32'

Answer (score 1):

Check your WinZip path. That needs to be fine fixed to the full path to your WinZip.

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba), try the below code:

```
Sub ExtractAllFiles()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim ShellStr
    FileName = Dir("C:\Downloads\*.gz")
    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        ShellStr = "winzip32 -e " & FileName & " C:\Downloads"
        Call Shell(ShellStr, vbHide)
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.